# convert DIVIDEND_EVENT to Dividend Event + javascript / angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any simple way to convert below.

Wants to replace _ with space and camelcase individual words.

DIVIDEND_EVENT to Dividend Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function camelize(string) {
  return string.split('_').map(function(item) {
    return item[0].toUpperCase() + item.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(" ");
}

console.log(camelize("DIVIDEND_EVENT")); // Dividend Event
```